# how to create a docker image with a conan package

Tags: docker, conan

I have an application available in jfrog, built for ubuntu. I want to create a docker image with this application.

I'm down the rabbit hole with a conanfile. conan install, conan build... but it seems like a dead end.

Anyone out there with a shovel to help me out of the pit?

Is there a way to get a specific conan application, with dependencies and make it into a docker file?

Comment: You need to install conan first, you can use pip, so you need to describe a profile for your environment, then you can install any package. You also can use [deploy](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/deploy.html) command to install package artifacts and copy to your system. I recommend you looking https://github.com/conan-io/conan-docker-tools as reference.

Comment: I have conan available. I was just in a jungle of install build... etc ill have a lokk at deploy. Thanks

Comment: I understand that you want to install a package and use it as part of your system. However, if you want to use your Docker image to build your application too, you should use conanfile.txt + conan install command to track the correct profile.

Comment: @uilianries do you a a sample of this?